# Finding the limit of the complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I am asked to find the limit $$\lim_{z \to \infty_{\mathbb{C}}} \frac{x^2y-x-2}{1-x}.$$ I have no clue how to solve this because we never covered limits like these?

Comment: $z$ isn't in the limit?

Comment: @DonThousand That’s the question he gave us. I am assuming he wants us to suppose $z=(x,y)$

Comment: And he did not define $\infty_\mathbb{C}$? Is it defined as $i\infty$?

Comment: @vitamind I have no clue. This course is really confusing to be honest. This is the question that’s in the notes.

Comment: @vitamind $\infty_{\mathbb C}$ generally means approaching infinity arbitrarily in $\mathbb C$. In any direction, essentially.

Comment: Okay thanks. See it for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what happens when $x$ is fixed (for example $x=2$) and $y$ goes to infinity? And what happens when $y=1/x$ and $x$ goes to infinity?